# Google maps, video and picture plugin not working in Django-CMS

Tags: google-maps, plugins, django-cms

I'm new to programing all together and definitely new to Django-CMS and Python, so excuse me if this is a simple answer.  All other plugins in my Django-CMS installation are working fine, but the Google Maps isn't working at all even though I have an API key in my settings file.  My picture plugin doesn't load the image, and the video plugin loads a missing flash plugin link to the Adobe Flash player website.  I'm running Chrome so that is already installed and updated.  I'm also using Django 1.2.5, Django-CMS 2.1.2, and Python 2.6.  I have tried to set CMS_PAGE_MEDIA_PATH, but that had no effect.  I have checked all error logs and have nothing out of order.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the details here, but one possible cause is that you don't have your media urls set to serve out correctly under the Django dev server; see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/#how-to-do-it .  Also be sure you have copied the DjangoCMS media into your media root.  I could imagine that could cause the maps video issues, at least.

If you've verified those things and you're still having problems, you can use the Chrome developer tools to see what the failing requests look like (reload the page with the "Network" tab, and look for 404s).  The URLs that are 404ing would be helpful in determining what aspect of serving media is not working.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the developer tools. They should shed a bit of light on the problem if the django dev server isn't throwing any errors.